# What is the difference between having separate arguments (for a function) or a struct of arguments?

Tags: c, struct

I have the code of a file compressor/decompressor, and I have to change the code to make it concurrent. I have a function called 'worker', that takes chunks from the in queue, runs them through a process (compress or decompress) and sends them to the out queue.

This is the 'worker' function header (with separate arguments):

`void worker(queue in, queue out, chunk (*process)(chunk));`

And this would be the 'worker' function if I had the arguments in a struct:

```
void worker(void *ptr) {
    chunk ch, res;
    struct args *args = ptr;
    while(q_elements(args->in) > 0) {
        ch = q_remove(args->in);

        res = args->process(ch);
        free_chunk(ch);

        q_insert(args->out, res);
    }
}
```

And the struct:

```
struct args {
    int thread_num;
    queue in;
    queue out;
    chunk (*process) (chunk);
};
```

Now, my question is: **What is the difference between passing separate arguments or a pointer to a struct of type args?**

Should I expect any difference? When should I take one option or another?

Comment: It's easy to reference an entire structure through a single variable. Like a callback taking a void* argument which could point to any sort of structure or context you'd like and the interface doesn't have to specify explicitly what you can or can't allow in a callback.

Comment: There is potentially a significant amount of additional overhead in calling the function with multiple arguments.  Also, in terms of code readability, it is easier for the human reader to understand a single argument than multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the benefit of having a pointer to a struct, is that when you are creating worker functions you typically use function pointers. Creating function pointers to functions with with argument of unspecified argument number and types is possible, but I would not recommend it.

For instance, if we have a look at `pthread_create`, it's prototype is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Here, `start_routine` is the worker function and `arg` is the arguments passed to it. It would be almost impossible to create a framework that is easy to use without this method.

> What is the difference between passing separate arguments or a pointer to a struct of type args? Should I expect any difference? When should I take one option or another?

As you saw in the above example, if you want to use `pthread` you simply have to do use structs.

Another use is if you want to hide implementation details for the programmer. It sorts of mimics OOP. Consider having this header:

```
// foobar.h
struct data;
int getId(struct data *data);
void setId(struct data *data, int id);
```

Now, for some reason, you don't want the programmer to access the fields in `data` directly. So we hide it's implementation in the source file:

```
// foobar.c
struct data {
    int id;
    // More fields
}

int getId(struct data *data) {
    return data->id;
}

void setID(struct data *data, int id) {
    data->id = id;
}
```

Similar reasoning can be used for a worker function.

A third reason can be that you have LOTS or arguments to pass. Then it can improve readability to use a struct instead.

Comment: Structs let you gives names to the parameters more visibly. `args a; a.visible = true; a.autohide = false; create(&a);` is clearer that you're creating a visible non-autohide object. Whereas `create(true, false)` is less obvious. Also, structs make it easier to establish defaults. `args a = default_args(); a.visible = true; create(&a)`; This creates a default object, except that it's visible. There could be 200 members of `args` but the only one you care about is `visible`.